# How can rm -rf be slower than delete in nautilus?

Tags: performance, gnome, rm, nautilus

I had this very surprising situation recently, while trying to delete folders containing many files (think code repo checkout with some 10 thousands files):

- When I tried to do this via command line as I normally would with `rm -rf` I waited for quite a while (say a minute?) without it finishing...
- On the other hand, when deleting folders of the same size in **nautilus** file browser, the delete was instantaneous - and not only so in the GUI, but the folder was also gone in the FS, as a `ls` on the terminal showed me.

So how can this be? Doesn't nautilus just execute 'normal' `rm`? Or is it equipped with some way of dealing with large tasks in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nautilus "deletes" files by moving them to the trash, and moving a file on the same filesystem is a very fast operation. You forgot to add the time taken emptying the trash into your observation.

Comment: That was sort of obvious, now I feel stupid. :)